# difference between tf.data.Dataset batch and map and tf.contrib.data.map_and_batch

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow-estimator

I created a tf.data.Dataset and want to train a model using this dataset:

```
dataset = dataset.prefeth()
dataset = dataset.shuffle()
dataset = dataset.repeat()
dataset = dataset.map()
dataset = dataset.filter()
dataset = dataset.batch()
```

I want to know what is the difference between the above dataset with the bellow one:

```
dataset = dataset.prefeth()
dataset = dataset.shuffle()
dataset = dataset.repeat()
dataset = dataset.apply(tf.contrib.data.map_and_batch())
```

I know that they should not be different except in performance. But I don't know should I use the .apply() method or not?

Is the first implementation correct?

Answer (score 2):

First off, most of the [tf.contrib.data](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/data) functions are deprecated and moved to [tf.data.experimental](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/experimental). So watch out for that.

Take a look at [input pipeline performance guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/performance/datasets#top_of_page) to get a good idea about what could be a good optimal ordering of the transformations for your application. Regarding map and batch, yes we pass the result of the map and batch to the apply function, and it is specified in the return description of [map and batch](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/experimental/map_and_batch) for reference confirmation. 
And we want to use map and batch for efficiency reasons, which normally depends on what your data is and how costly your map function is. The performance guide has some guidelines for the same.

Regarding the difference between your first and second blocks of code, there is a filter function in between, so both blocks might not give the same result depending on what you are filtering.

Comment: Thanks, The reason for the first code is I want to filter my dataset and that's why I had to use map and batch separately. Do you think that predicate in filter method could cause any problem like process hanging or stalling?

Comment: @Hamed it depends a lot on your application. You can always use the num_parallel_calls argument to maybe speed up the computation of your map, if your map function can benefit from that. If its pretty important that you need to filter after you map and not anywhere else in this pipeline, I would just treat it as the cost of your application reflected in the pipeline

Comment: thanks @kvish. Actually I have to use filter. right now I don't care about performance. I asked another question which explains more my problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54221770/what-happens-if-number-of-samples-changes-every-epoch-using-tf-data-dataset-filt