# What happens if number of samples changes every epoch using tf.data.Dataset filter method? (my program hangs)

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I want to have different number of samples on every epoch. For example at epoch 1 I want to have 100 samples (all samples) and at the second epoch I want only 50 samples. Right now, I'm doing this using tf.data.Dataset filter method. I'm using [models/official/resnet](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/official/resnet) tf code and using multi gpus.

My problem:
after random number of epochs, the program hangs and even CTRL+C cannot kill the program. My questions is:
Would the different number of samples per epoch cause any problem?

my filter's predicate function returns true or false based on one condition applied for each sample. I'm wondering if some hooks or other things depend on number of training samples at the beginning and when the number of samples is decreased, they wait for more sampels which is not available and probably that's why my program hangs (no gpu utilization).

I create my dataset as the following:

```
dataset = dataset.prefetch(buffer_size=batch_size)
dataset = dataset.shuffle()
dataset = dataset.repeat(1)
dataset = dataset.map(parse samples)
dataset = dataset.filter(my predicate on each samples)
dataset = dataset.batch()
dataset = dataset.prefetch(buffer_size=tf.contrib.data.AUTOTUNE)
```

For training I'm using tf.estimator.

Comment: can you share more details on your training code and how you use multiple GPU's? You have used repeat(1) here so you are repeating your dataset once, have you set the no of epochs corresponding to this figure?

Comment: Actually I'm using the tf/models/official/resnet code base which uses the estimator. I call estimator.train function 90 times and each time repeat the dataset only once which is the same as repeating the dataset 90 times and call train() only once. My question is: Could the above code snippet cause any hands in tf?

Comment: In the estimator function this is not quite the case. Everytime you call the train method it constructs the graph of operations from scratch again. I'm guessing your program hangs because it has too many graphs that are created. You should replace the code with calling train once and repeating for the no of epochs you want.